# Value converter not loading images in Tree View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm a beginner at C#.  Trying to follow this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OwyNiLPDNw

I've currently created a TreeView to display all the folders/files in the system as described in the above video.  I've added a valueConverter class to change the icon based on if the item is a drive/folder/file.  Have three files for that accordingly.  Now, the problem, I'm facing is that, when I run the program, there's no exception thrown, but the images are not displayed. If I add a static image file in the corresponding xaml file, I see that it's displayed.  But if I used a valueConverter, it's not.  I single stepped into the program, and I can see that my valueConverter function is being successfully called and the corresponding image is chosen as well.  I don't understand why the image is not being displayed.

Any help is highly appreciated !

Code for my xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_TreeView.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_TreeView"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <TreeView x:Name="FolderView">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Width="100" Margin="3" 
                                       Source="{Binding 
                                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}},
                                       Path=Tag,
                                       Converter={x:Static local:HeaderToImageConverter.Instance}}"/>
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>


        </TreeView.Resources>
```

Code for my Value Converter:

```
namespace Wpf_TreeView
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a full path to a specific image type of a drive,folder or a file
    /// </summary>

    [ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(BitMapImage))]
    public class HeaderToImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public static HeaderToImageConverter Instance = new HeaderToImageConverter();

        //public static HeaderToImageConverter Instance { get => instance; set => instance = value; }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //Get the full path
            var path = (string)value;

            //Check if path is null
            if (path == null) return null;

            //Get the name of the file/folder
            var name = MainWindow.GetFileFolderName(path);

            // By default we presume file image
            var image = "Images/file.png";

            // If the name is blank, we assume it's a drive (file/folder) cannot have blank name
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                image = "Images/drive.png";
            }
            else if (new FileInfo(path).Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory))
            {
                image = "Images/folder.jpg";
            }
            //the below statement does not seem to work although image contains the proper string as expected
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri($"pack://application:,,,/{image}")); 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that the image files are located in a folder named "Images" in your Visual Studio project, and that their Build Action is set to Resource.

Comment: As a note, you should make the Instance field readonly, or declare it as readonly property like `public static HeaderToImageConverter Instance { get; } = new HeaderToImageConverter();`

Comment: Yes, the Images folder is in the visual studio project and the build action is set to resource.  I tried clean -> build as well, but the issue persists !

Comment: Whoever did the correction, many thanks ! The problem was , I was using the BitMap instead of Bitmap.

Comment: How did that compile before the edit? Anyway, if the problem is solved, you should delete the question.

Comment: Why delete it ? It might help somebody else who might be in similar situation.  It didn't give me compilation errors. I'm assuming there's either a BitMap in another namespace or the alt+enter performed some correction, that I'm unaware of.  Should be careful using 'alt+enter' in the future.

Answer (score -2):

The solution was to use `BitmapImage` instead of `BitMapImage`. Should be wary of using alt+enter without paying attention to what it does !

Comment: Of course there is no BitMapImage in the framework. Apparently Visual Studio created it in your project. This answer is useless for any future reader.